# Changeable cell phone battery pack

Tags: splitters, battery

I sometimes need 10kmah and sometimes 20kmah and would prefer not buy 2 separate battery packs.  Money is no object.  Is there a cell phone USB charger that is chainable?

Comment: What do you mean, chainable?  Also, what is kmah?

Comment: @Alex I can hook multiple battery packs together and 1,000 mah.

Comment: Which device would you need these for? I think chainable battery packs are device-specific. Also, mAh = milliAmpere hours.  So 1000 mAh = 1Ah.

Comment: @Alex "Is there a cell phone USB charger that is chainable?"

Comment: Is there a reason the SE posts linked on your profile have been removed by you, but remain in your profile?

Comment: @Alex I guess someone deleted them.  Some were by me some by others probably.  I mean if a question gets closed there is little sense in keeping it on the site.

Answer (score 1):

If I understood you correctly, a "cell phone USB charger" is a power bank.  If that's right, then as far as I am aware, you have two options:

- Buy a 20Ah charger that has multiple batteries inside, wired in parallel.  When you need 10Ah, take out half the batteries; when you need 20Ah, put them back in.  Example: [4 batteries inside](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B012NIQG5E). [3 batteries inside](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B01EWURK6U). [8 batteries inside (but you must take out 4 at a time).](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B07BVSVCQF)
- Buy two 10Ah power banks, and a [two-to-one USB cable](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00NIGO4NM), which would allow to use both of them at the same time if that's what you need.  You can put them both in a single case, to make sure they stay as a unit.  Using both simultaneously is particularly useful if your device uses a lot of power.

Comment: Can I keep chaining those battery packs together with the splitters?

Comment: Theoretically, yes; in practice, though, every time you have a connection, you lose a certain amount of Voltage; and therefore, you would want to avoid having more than 2 connections before your charging device. The other problem is, that female-to-multimale connectors are quite rare; so the most you can do is 4-to-1 using this method, using three cables. Anything more, and you'd have to solder the cable yourself. Link for cheapest 3 cables: https://www.ebay.com/itm/Lot-of-3-USB-Extension-Splitter-Data-Cables-2-0-Female-To-Dual-USB-Male-2-0-Y/311971115829?hash=item48a2ed7335:g:ESAAAOSwnOVamJ10